# Django with mySQL

Tags: django

I have successfully set up and used Django with MySQL on my local machine, but now if I put my project on say GitHub what should the requirements be for any other person to be able to run it?

I am asking this because my project uses a database that I have stored in my local machine and while uploading the project on GitHub I have not uploaded the database. in sqlite3 there is a database file inside the project itself but this does not happen for MySQL whose database is stored in a different location.

I mean Django accesses the database from a different location(var/lib/MySQL) and when I try to copy the database from there to the project folder and specify its location in settings.py, I get an access denied error.
So how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You would typically have a seed file for others to use. Others will create a database on their own systems and use your seed file to get started with the project.

Answer (score 1):

It should not be necessary to *copy* the database files. Also, you should not just copy the MySQL directory like that. If you copy the whole directory then you might replace what somebody already has on their system, but if you copy only some of the files then you might be missing things like the MySQL user accounts. Besides, that is a *backup* procedure, not a *deployment* or *distribution* procedure.

For somebody else to get started with your project the normal process is:

1. manually create the appropriate MySQL user and database (or provide a script to automate it)
2. Run migrations: `python manage.py migrate`
3. Import initial data:

   - This can be with [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/initial-data/): `python manage.py loaddata my_data.json`
   - Or with a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/): `python manage.py load_my_data`

However, if you *really* need to provide somebody with an almost ready database, you can use [`mysqldmp`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) which will produce a SQL text file, but the other person still needs to create the user account manually.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add some with [himank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8958336/himank) that if you need to provide some additional data for database you can up your `fixture-data`[link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/initial-data/) in fixture folder. Then other person will able to load those manually with command or even able to run a script [link](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runscript.html) to populate initially data to database.